# List inside an HTML Tag -PowerShell

Tags: html, list, powershell

I have a PoweShell command that lists all files from my path.

I need to list when I do HTML tag to send an e-mail.

Here is my code,

```
# To List File
$listFiles =  Get-ChildItem -path $mypath
```

In my Email Message Body:

```
$emailMessage.Body = @"
                <h4>Folder Path: </h4><p>$mypath</p>
                <h3> List of files: </h3>
                <li>$listFiles</li>
"@
```

I get this,

```
Folder Path: 
C:my_tes\test_file_path

List of files:

•  Test_Document_1.txt Test_Document_2.txt WorkBook_Test_1.xlsx
```

But I need this,

```
Folder Path: 
C:my_tes\test_file_path

List of files: 
•  Test_Document_1.txt 
•  Test_Document_2.txt 
•  WorkBook_Test_1.xlsx
```

I tried the following(did not get what I want),

```
$emailMessage.Body = @"
                <h4>Folder Path: </h4><p>$mypath</p>
                <h3> List of files: </h3>
                Foreach(<li>$i</li> in $listFiles)
```

How can I modify my `<li>` html tag to get the desired output?

Comment: Just add a loop.

Comment: Try `Foreach($i in $listFiles) { "<li>$i</li>" }`

Comment: @Ellis I am getting `Foreach(in Test_Document_1.txt Test_Document_2.txt WorkBook_Test_1.xlsx) { "
• " }`

Comment: @Ellis I think you're getting close, but when I use `$listAllFiles` in e-mail body given `$listAllFiles = Foreach($item in $listFiles) {
    "<li>$item</li>"
}` it does not print anything in e-mail body. It is empty.

Comment: @Ellis I got it, your answer helped me, I wrapped your previously posted answer into `<ul>$listAllFiles</ul>` and it gives everything. You deserve an upvote for your answer to lead me to the solution, but I don't see your answer anymore :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, I deleted it thinking it didn't help. But if it did, I'd appreciate the upvote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output an Unordered list, you also need to enclose the `<li>..</li>` elements inside `<ul>..</ul>` tags.

The eastiest thing to do is to build the list of file tags straight from the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet:

```
$listFiles =  Get-ChildItem -Path $mypath -File | ForEach-Object { '<li>{0}</li>' -f $_.Name }
$emailMessage.Body = @"
    <h4>Folder Path: </h4><p>$mypath</p>
    <h3> List of files: </h3>
    <ul>$listFiles</ul>
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this above your existing code:

```
$listFiles = Foreach($item in $listFiles) {
    "<li>$item</li>"
}
```

Then using `$listItems` in your email body where the loop is.